# Why I can't use parameter pack in the constructor

Tags: c++, c++17, parameter-pack

Here is my code in hpp:

```
template <size_t... Bits>
class TelemetryCompactDataStrategy : public TelemetryCommonDataStrategy
{
    static_assert((Bits + ...) <= 32, "Bit count must not exceed 32.");

public:
    static constexpr auto bitSize  = (Bits + ...);
    static constexpr auto dataSize = (bitSize + 7) / 8;
    TelemetryCompactDataStrategy(QString... paths, QObject* parent = nullptr)
        : TelemetryCommonDataStrategy({paths, ...}, dataSize, parent), m_args({paths, ...})
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Bits) == sizeof...(paths), "Number of bits and values must match.");
    }

    QByteArray toByteArray() override
    {
        uint32_t value = 0;
        currentIndex   = 0;
        writeBits<0>(value, m_values);

        QByteArray byteArray;
        byteArray.append(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&value), dataSize);
        return (dataSize == m_dataSize) ? byteArray : QByteArray(m_dataSize, 0x00);
    }

    int          validTelemetryDataCount() override { return m_args.size(); }
    QVariantHash toVariantHash(QByteArray datas) override { return {}; }

protected:
    void processedTelemetryValue() override
    {
        m_values = m_rawValues;
    }

private:
    std::array<QString, sizeof...(Bits)> m_args;
    size_t                               currentIndex = 0;

    template <size_t Index>
    void writeBits(uint32_t& value, const QMap<QString, QVariant>& values)
    {
        constexpr size_t BitCount = BitsAtIndex<Index>();

        if (currentIndex + BitCount > 32)
            throw std::runtime_error("Bit count exceeds 32.");

        const auto valueToAdd = values[m_args[Index]].toInt() & ((1 << BitCount) - 1);
        value |= (valueToAdd << currentIndex);

        currentIndex += BitCount;
        if constexpr (Index + 1 < sizeof...(Bits))
            writeBits<Index + 1>(value, values);
    }

    template <size_t Index>
    static constexpr size_t BitsAtIndex()
    {
        if constexpr (Index < sizeof...(Bits))
            return Bits + ... + (Index * 0); // Force evaluation of Bits at Index
        else
            return 0;
    }
};
```

I want my class construct with several QString values, but when I instantiate a object like:

```
new TelemetryCompactDataStrategy<2, 1, 1, 2, 1>(getTelemetryDataInfo("LowBeamLight").path,
                                                        getTelemetryDataInfo("RainLight").path,
                                                        getTelemetryDataInfo("Wipers").path,
                                                        getTelemetryDataInfo("EngineIgnition").path,
                                                        getTelemetryDataInfo("TyreType").path,
                                                        this)
```

it seems that this does not work, how should I modify my hpp or how should I do to realise such a class to contain variety of bits like this class?

I've checked those documents on cppreference.com, It demonstrates using template<typename... Type>, I wonder if I can't use a real type like QString? this only supports templete type like func(T&& ...path)? Hope somebody save me!

Comment: Edit your question with the actual error you get and please try to reduce it to a [mre]. We do not know what your `TelemetryCommonDataStrategy` looks like or what `this` refers to in your usage example.

Comment: what is the meaning of "it seems that this does not work" ?

Comment: `QString... paths` is not a parameter pack. For [parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) you need templates.

Comment: it looks like you are confusing [varargs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic), the c way of variadic functions with c++ variadic functions via variadic templates. Despite similar look and use of `...`, its two completely different stories.

Comment: its unclear why you think you need a parameter pack for the constructor in the first place. Use `std::vector` or `std::initializer_list` or if you want to keep the check for matching size a `std::array<QString, sizeof...Bits>`

Comment: You already have a `std::array<QString, sizeof...(Bits)>` member, so why not take the same type as argument in your constructor?

Comment: @Botje I'm sorry about the confusing I made in the description, but my error info showed in Chinese and I think it may not help you all, the error code is C3543 and message is { "const QString&": Contains no parameter package }. About the base class (TelemetryCommonDataStrategy), it concerns nothing to this error, it just provide the m_values member object that are a QMap<QString,QVariant>.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I really does not know about how to used the variadic templates, this code originated from ChatGPT and i just have it a little modified, for the reason why I want to use parameter pack instead of using vector\array and so on, it's basically because it's much more a intuitive realisation, you know, how many templates I gave I will also have a constructor that contains parameters in that number.

Comment: @Nelfeal Because I think the variable parameter template in this requirement corresponds to a variable parameter constructor is a more intuitive implementation

Comment: Please don't add "solved" to the title, or any solutions to the question itself. Pressing a checkmark next to an answer is enough to mark the question as solved, and if you want to share your solution, you should post your own answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only expend template parameter pack, so `QString... paths` is invalid.

Several alternatives:

- Use `std::array<QString, sizeof...(Bits)>` (or other containers)

  ```
  template <size_t... Bits>
  class TelemetryCompactDataStrategy : public TelemetryCommonDataStrategy
  {
      TelemetryCompactDataStrategy(std::array<QString, sizeof...(Bits)> paths, QObject* parent = nullptr)
          : TelemetryCommonDataStrategy(paths, dataSize, parent), m_args(std::move(paths))
      {
      }
  // ...
  };
  ```

  calling site would have extra `{..}` around your `QString`.
- Use some trick to "convert" `Bits` into `QString`:

  ```
  template <typename T, std::size_t>
  using always_t = T;

  #if 0 // Alternative for buggy compiler
  template <typename T, std::size_t>
  struct always
  {
      using type = T;
  };
  template <typename T, std::size_t I>
  using always_t = typename always<T, I>::type;
  #endif
  ```

  And then

  ```
  template <size_t... Bits>
  class TelemetryCompactDataStrategy : public TelemetryCommonDataStrategy
  {
      TelemetryCompactDataStrategy(always_t<QString, Bits>... paths, QObject* parent = nullptr)
          : TelemetryCommonDataStrategy({paths...}, dataSize, parent), m_args({paths...})
      {
      }
  // ...
  };
  ```
- Use template constructor:

  ```
  template <size_t... Bits>
  class TelemetryCompactDataStrategy : public TelemetryCommonDataStrategy
  {
      template <typename... Ts
  #if 1 // C++17 SFINAE
                , std::enable_if_t<,
                   sizeof...(Ts) == sizeof...(Bits) && 
                   (std::is_constructible_v<QString, Ts> && ...)
                int> = 0
  #endif
      >
  #if 0 // For C++20, to replace SFINAE
      requires (sizeof...(Ts) == sizeof...(Bits)
            && (std::is_constructible_v<QString, Ts> && ...))
  #endif
      TelemetryCompactDataStrategy(Ts... paths, QObject* parent = nullptr)
          : TelemetryCommonDataStrategy({paths...}, dataSize, parent), m_args({paths...})
      {
      }
  // ...
  };
  ```

Comment: "expend template" -> "expand template parameter pack" ? And afaik `QString... paths` is not invalid, its just not a parameter pack, but an ellipsis for c-like variadic functions, not what OP wants i suppose

Comment: In OP case, as it is the last non defaulted argument is it indeed `QString, ...`. :-/

Comment: oh right, I missed the `,` for the varargs and got mislead by some weird gcc extension.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I used the second trick and it did solved this error. But this class compiles still have a error of: "MSVC(C1001): internal compiler error", I have to solve this error now... Anyway, thank you so much for your solution.

Comment: Direct alias might be problematic with "buggy" compiler. Alternative implementation added which might avoid some ICE.

Comment: One could probably do something with `std::enable_if_t` (with an always-true condition) to avoid writing a helper template for (2).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of yourselves, with the help of @Jarod42 , finally my class finished like this, it compress numeric values to one uint32_t, this matches my requirement and I post it here if this may help someone. Anyway thanks all of you for your helpful advices.

```
template <typename T, std::size_t>
using always_t = T;

template <size_t... Bits>
class TelemetryCompactDataStrategy : public TelemetryCommonDataStrategy
{
    static_assert((Bits + ...) <= 32, "Bit count must not exceed 32.");

public:
    static constexpr auto bitSize  = (Bits + ...);
    static constexpr auto dataSize = (bitSize + 7) / 8;

    TelemetryCompactDataStrategy(always_t<QString, Bits>... paths, QObject* parent = nullptr)
        : TelemetryCommonDataStrategy({paths...}, dataSize, parent), m_args({paths...})
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(Bits) == sizeof...(paths), "Number of bits and values must match.");
    }

    QByteArray toByteArray() override
    {
        uint32_t value = 0;
        writeBits<0, dataSize * 8>(value, m_values);

        QByteArray byteArray;
        byteArray.append(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&value), dataSize);
        return (dataSize == m_dataSize) ? byteArray : QByteArray(m_dataSize, 0x00);
    }

    ...

private:
    std::array<QString, sizeof...(Bits)> m_args;

    /**
     * @brief 算出指定Index位置的数据有占用多少个bit
     * 
     * @tparam Index 数据的索引
     * @return constexpr size_t 数据占用的长度 bit
     */
    template <size_t Index>
    static constexpr size_t BitsAtIndex()
    {
        // 使用递归调用和模板特化来获取对应位置的模板参数值
        return std::get<Index>(std::tuple(Bits...));
    }
    /**
     * @brief 在value中写入各个位置的数据，数据集来自values
     * 
     * @tparam Index 要写入的数据的模板的index
     * @tparam offSet 写入到value的偏移bit数
     * @param value 写入到的value
     * @param values 数据来源集合
     */
    template <size_t Index, size_t offSet>
    void writeBits(uint32_t& value, const QVariantHash& values)
    {
        constexpr size_t BitCount = BitsAtIndex<Index>();

        const auto valueToAdd = values[m_args[Index]].toInt() & ((1 << BitCount) - 1);
        value |= (valueToAdd << offSet);

        if constexpr (Index + 1 < sizeof...(Bits))
            writeBits<Index + 1, offSet - BitCount>(value, values);
    }
};
```